VisualVM not listing my JBOSS Java application
I am using Visual VM to analyse the JVM but when i start the Visual VM, i am not getting my Java process listed in the Local. I even tried running the Visual VM as Administrator but still i cant see the process.
Application is running in java-11-openjdk-11.0.10-1 and jboss-eap-7.4.
Any idea how to get my application in the Local section of the Visual VM?
Visual VM Screenshot
This is the Java process, i want to monitor

JDK 11 is rather dated, don't you think?   JDK 21 is the current LTS version.   Maybe this link can help: https://www.baeldung.com/visualvm-jmx-remote

Thanks for the reply. We are running a legacy application created by a Vendor and they have stopped their support for this application and we have to work this legacy application by fixing issues it encounters. Business don't want to take any risk of upgrading the JDK and create any issue to the application as we don't have support from the Vendor. We have not upgraded the Windows Server itself to the latest version and it is still running in version 2012 as we dont want to try and break this Java application.

i tried adding the below parameters and my JBOSS Service is not starting.
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

i just noticed that the Jboss application is running with another admin account but i have logged in with different Admin account. Do i have to login as the same user that is running the JBoss application. Any workaround for this?

What a silly client.   Find a smarter one.

I'm not a Windows expert, but my guess is yes you need to use the same user that started the JBoss EAP process to connect with Visual VM.

To be listed under the “local” node, the process has to run under the same user. You can still add a remote connection to a process running under a different user by hand but, of course, this requires that the target process has been set up to accept remote JMX connections. So you need to find out why your service is not starting with those options.
